# Minecraft Fire Place

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to build a fireplace in Minecraft that can:

1. Be self-lighting
2. Extinguish itself
3. Have a log cabin feel to it
4. Have it connect with a light switch
5. Have the flames 2 blocks high

I'm open to all ideas.

Comment: that's not possible in vanilla Minecraft you will have to download a mod if you want it to all be possible

Comment: although some of it is possible without a mod

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made one of these a long time ago. Here's a screenshot of the fireplace design:

[image]

It's a corner design with three fires burning on top of [netherack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Netherack), and the switch at the left turns it on and off. I'll address each of your points separately for this design:

1. **Self-lighting:** Since I made this in an older version of Minecraft, it uses [fire charges](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire_Charge) shot from [dispensers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dispenser) behind the brick blocks at the back of the fire place. As noted by others, newer versions of Minecraft allow you to place a [flint and steel](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Flint_and_Steel) in a dispenser to light blocks in front of it on fire, which is how you'll probably want to go. The dispensers are activated by a [falling-edge detector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pulse_circuit#fed) circuit connected to the switch that delivers a pulse when it is flipped up.
2. **Extinguish itself:** The netherack blocks that the fire is on are being held up by extended [sticky pistons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Piston). A [rising edge detector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pulse_circuit#red) circuit connects from the switch to an inverter (i.e. [redstone torch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Torch)) under the pistons. The pistons are briefly retracted when the switch is flipped down, and the movement of the netherack blocks puts out the fire on top of them.
3. **Log-cabin feel:** Well, as you can see I went for obsidian. However, you can build with wood if you are careful to use brick blocks and other non-flammables in proximity to your flames. Based on [how fire spreads](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire#Spread) in Minecraft, the area you have to be wary of is a region 1 block below, 1 block around (including diagonals) and 4 blocks above your flame. In other words, a 3-by-3-by-6 column. If you can fill that entire region with non-flammable, *non-air* blocks, you're good. If there are any air blocks in that column, you have to leave a block of space between them and any flammable blocks.
4. **Controlled by a switch:** Check! ;)
5. **2-block-high flames:** Can't help you there. I doubt it's even possible.

Comment: That is an attractive fireplace!

Answer (score 11):

You can do most of this, apart from having the flames 2 blocks high.

You can trigger fire using flint & steel dispensers, which you can turn on with redstone. To extinguish the fire have another dispenser quickly place a water block where the fire is. There are other methods too, [this one by DerpCrafturrr](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0mvARhQRks) is particularly good.

You will need to set the `doFireTick` gamerule to False if you don't want your logs to burn down.

As for the log cabin ambience, that's all a matter of design, but [this building guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbuwv.jpg) should help you make things look awesome!

Comment: I'm using netherrack for the fuel if that helps.

Comment: Couldn't you do it 2 blocks tall with /summon ?

Comment: Just to add to this, as of a recent version, Flint & Steel can be placed in a dispenser and will ignite the block directly in front when the dispenser is activated. It's a little easier to make than Blaze Charges.

Comment: @RavenM no, you can't "/summon" fire! although you technically can summon fire-charges fire cannot stack so even if you could summon fire, the top fire would go out immediately

Comment: also @Studoku is right though. that is the best you can do without mods

Comment: @RavenM fire is a block so you would be able to do this with setblock, but you'll need to set the data to 0xf or it burns itself out very fast (it checks whether the block it is on is burnable)

Comment: @Awesomest_Donut I meant to say setblock.(I get them confused)